# ImageView not taking shape of the card View, before it was working fine and now something went wrong which i couldnt figure it out

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview, cardview

ImageView not taking corner radius of cardView [check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxjQv.jpg)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:elevation="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp">
                <ImageView
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/white2"
                        android:background="@color/white2"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:id="@+id/pending_image_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

am stuck can some one help me?

Comment: remove elevation and check it, it not works then remove background on imageview

Comment: thank you, but still not working

Comment: otherwise use custom border as background only on topLeft corner has radius

Comment: sir it was working fine before and i dint change the code, after few builds i encountered this

Answer (score 0):

Don't make `cardview` as parent layout, the following code is working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for your answere but card view is not parent layout its just a snippet i posted any other solution you have?

Comment: before it was working for me!! suddenly something went wrong